# Google Play Saved Game download is corrupt after reinstalling application

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

When my application is re-installed, the download of the google play saved game data is sometimes corrupt.

To reproduce:

- I upload my 5870 byte binary save game to the cloud using snapshot.getSnapshotContents().writeBytes(Data);
- I can then download this correctly using snapshot.getSnapshotContents().readFully();
- Remove and reinstall the app
- Upon startup the snapshot will download, it will be the correct size, but will have some corruption, usually 16 bytes.
- using two devices it is possible to seemingly receive two different sets of data from readFully(). The device which reinstalls will receive a corrupt copy, and the device which doesn't will receive the correct copy.

So, reinstalling seems to cause a change in what is received through the snapshot.readfully() function which is out of my control. No conflicts in the snapshot data are present, and I can reliably reproduce this scenario with my application.

I have found no workaround, and it is currently affecting some users who attempt to reinstall the app and restore their game progress.

I have tried using GooglePlayServices revisions 19, 20 and 22 with the same results.

Is anyone else seeing this issue, and is there any way I can work around or fix it?

Comment: Maybe you should file an issue at Google directly?
https://code.google.com/p/play-games-platform/issues/list

Comment: Thanks, I did and they are looking into it. I still thought a post here would be useful to see how widespread the issue is, and find out if anyone has been able to implement a workaround for it...

Comment: I developed an app that use snapshots, never has the issue. Or I'm not aware of...

Answer (score 0):

Google have now confirmed this issue as identified and fixed. The fix was server side, so nothing is required from app developers.